# MLPRegressor Output Range

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I am using Scikit's `MLPRegressor` for a timeseries prediction task.

My data is scaled between 0 and 1 using the `MinMaxScaler` and my model is initialized using the following parameters:

```
MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=50,
                           max_iter=10000, shuffle=False, random_state=9876,
                           activation='relu')
```

I am expecting output between 0 and 1 but getting values outside the bound (both negative values as well as > 1).

Non-normalized data has the same problem, I get predictions out of range!

Any idea where I could be wrong?

Comment: You say your data is scaled. Are your targets scaled? Those you are trying to predict? If so, how. Show complete code and some samples. Regression tasks may predict the targets (slightly out of trained data) if prediction (test) data is out of range. But without samples we cant help.

Comment: @VivekKumar, its a time-series and the entire data is scaled to [0,1]. The inputs and targets are made out of the original series using sliding windows, so yes inputs and targets are all scaled accordingly.

Comment: Well, I guess my question is general and does not depend on code. Is it an expected behaviour from `MLPRegressor`? I would assume that the predicted values should not go over the range of training data, but I maybe wrong in my assumption, if so my question is how to force the regressor to stick to the given data range?

Comment: Of course they can. See my first comment. And if you think your question does not depend on code, please post on https://stats.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is for programming errors generally.

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion here! The discussion there are much useful and related to the question above!
[mlpregressor-output-range](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31957/mlpregressor-output-range)